# Why is my sprite not moving

Tags: python, class, pygame, sprite

My sprite should be moving from right to left across the screen, and there should be multiple of the same sprites moving from random Y co-ordinates, where as the X should stay the same. Instead, at the moment, there is no movement and there is only on of the sprites.

```
            class Mob(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
                def __init__(self, x, y):
                    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
                    self.image = pygame.Surface((90, 90)).convert_alpha()
                    self.image = pygame.image.load(badguy_file).convert_alpha()
                    self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (100, 100))
                    self.rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, 100, 100)
                    self.x = x
                    self.y = y
                    self.rect.x = random.randrange(800 - 100)
                    self.rect.y = random.randrange(-100, -40)
                    self.speedx = 5
                    self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.image)

                def update(self):
                    self.rect.y += self.speedy
                    if self.rect.top > height + 10 or self.rect.left < -25 or self.rect.right > width + 20:
                        self.rect.x = random.randrange(width - self.rect.width)
                        self.rect.y = random.randrange(-100, -40)
                        self.speedx = random.randrange(2,0)

                def render(self, screen):
                    screen.blit(self.image, (self.x, self.y))

            mobYRange = random.randrange(200, 450)

            mobs = pygame.sprite.Group()       
            for i in range(8):
                mob = Mob(850,mobYRange)
                mobs.add(mob)
                mob.render(screen)
```

Comment: If you are not using the for loop variable (in this case `i`) you can call it `_` instead to indicate that it is unused/irrelevant. I.e `for _ in range(8):`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have actual random y-axis, since once generated random list is passed to all instances of the Mob, use code below:

```
mobs = pygame.sprite.Group()       
for i in range(8):
    mob = Mob(850, random.randrange(200, 450))
    mobs.add(mob)
    mob.render(screen)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you choose the y coord you do it like this `mobYRange = random.randrange(200, 450)` and then you use the SAME coord for all your mobs. You need to move the call of `randrange` into the for loop where you create your `Mob`s.

Also I'm not sure how pygame works. But are you supposed to call `screen.blit()` just once? I would have guessed this is something you call every frame to keep drawing it to the screen.